# How to apply slice operator to get n-th column of an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have 2-D matrix of size `n`, I want to get the entire `n-1`th column values into another list. For example,

```py
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
a[:][0] // return [1,2]
```

how to get 1,3,5 for above `a` 2-D array into a list using slice operator

Comment: strictly using the slice operator?

Comment: Yes, if possible

Comment: Hope it is possible? if not, please answer it as not possible.

Comment: I'm not aware of a solution with the slice operator (admittedly I don't have much experience with python). I wold recommend list comprehensions.

Comment: If you aren't tied to using lists strictly, you might want to consider numpy, esp if you only have numbers and all rows have the same number of elements. You can slice like this: `a[:, -2]`.

Comment: @busybears - Yes, I simplified to numbers, but in our case it can have any data type 2-D array. Thank you for your comments, I accept the answer as it is not possible for 2-D array/list in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, the array slice operator is not suited for what you're looking for.

I would recommend python's [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```py
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

result = [x[0] for x in a]
print(result)
```

Comment: yes, using list compression we can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `numpy` library:

```
import numpy

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
result = a[:, 0]   # Returns a 1-D numpy array [1, 3, 5]
```

More advanced indexing and slicing options can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html).

Comment: since numpy doest comes under python default package I can't accept this answer. very nice trick.

Comment: That's fine. You can select any answer that is best for you. But if your code needs to do lots of matrix processing you may want to consider using numpy.